# How have the calculations to determine Hidden Power's type changed with the introduction of Fairy?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I've been looking into getting a specific type for Hidden Power, but the best I can find is the (now outdated) Smogon [Hidden Power Guide](http://www.smogon.com/ingame/guides/breeding_guide_part4#general_information).

The Sixth Generation of Pokemon has introduced the Fairy type, throwing the value-table out of whack. So, what are the values needed to get particular types?

Comment: As the power is now always the same, they might have used the data previously used to determine the power. Other than that, since it probably still works with Odd/Even IVs, there is a theoretical pool of 64 combinations, they could have simply reassigned some of them. If you have a lot of Pokemon whose IVs you know, you can just check their HP type and make a list. I unfortunately have nearly no pokemon whose IVs I know exactly...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[According to Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Hidden_Power_%28move%29) (emphasis mine):

> Hidden Power's base power is now 60, and like in previous generations, its type is determined by the user's IVs. **As the method for determining the type of Hidden Power is the same as Generation III to V, a Fairy-type Hidden Power is not possible.**

Comment: Wow, that's a bummer...